# Is there anything in Jersey similar to RESTEasy's MockDispatcherFactory and MockHttpRequest?

Tags: mocking, jersey, resteasy

Our project is evaluating porting to Jersey, because it is now the default standard.

Most of the migration is straightforward, but we're stuck on mocking.

RESTEasy has a mocking framework, org.resteasy.mock.*, that makes it easy to write end-to-end tests that run quickly, exercise the bulk of the functionality in a web service, and don't require a container. It's very useful.

Is there something like that in Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

Asked around and was pointed to this: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html.

Along with some additional explanation:

It is slightly different from RESTEasy.

You can directly invoke REST resource methods to test rest endpoints. To inject Jersey-specific objects (@Context, @HttpServletRequest, etc.), use JMockit.

Or run an inline Jetty container (one of the lightweight ones that doesn't require Tomcat) and invoke endpoints as an external client.